# How to increase the scroll rate when the down arrow key is pressed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard

I see options for the mouse wheel, but when I hold the down arrow key, I would like it to move faster than it currently does. Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try an extension that does what you want. For example this one:
[Yet Another Smooth Scrolling](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5846/).

It has support for the latest Firefox version and it provides:

- increasing step size for scrolling with cursor keys;
- a built-in smooth scrolling.

Comment: Thanks! I usually avoid the smooth scrollers because they make it slower. But I tried SmoothScroll and love it.